# How to return javascript when i call mvc3 function

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I am working on a project in which i give a code
to user he will embed that link in his site and some content
of my site will show on his site .Following is the  code

```
<div id="survey">
<div>
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="www.example.com/exampleaction"> </script>
</div>
</div>
```

In c#

```
public ActionResult exampleaction(){
// Some thing to do which returns javascript as a source  
}
```

and following is the javascript code that written in my file which i want to
send

```
if(document.getElementById('survey'))
{document.getElementById('survey').style.border='1px solid #ccc';
 document.getElementById('survey').style.padding='4px';
 document.getElementById('survey').style.width='500px';
 document.getElementById('survey').style.fontSize='10px';
 document.getElementById('survey').style.color='#666';
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could change your C# method to:

```
public ActionResult exampleaction()
{
    return JavaScript("your JavaScript code.");
}
```

It's up to you how you populate the string, you could read it in from a text file and return the contents...

Answer (score 0):

```
return Content("Your Content Here");
```

however why not just have them style it properly with a link to your css if all you are doing is styling the div?
I imagine there's more going on here though than you posted.